# Workaround for calling private method in baseclass from subclass in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, class, encapsulation, prototype-programming

```
base = function () {
  this.A = function () {
    this.B();
  }
  this.B = function () {} // ABSTRACT!
  var E = function () {
    alert('I am E');
  }
}

sub = function () {
  this.B = function () {
    alert('I am B');
  }
  this.D = function () {
    E();
  }
}

sub.prototype = new base();
```

Situation 1:

```
(new sub()).D();
```

This doesn't work, as expected, since D and E are in different closures.  I want to keep E private, since it should never be invoked directly (i.e. on an instance).  I understand the reason for not being allowed to access E is to ensure encapsulation, but what can I do?  My only two options appear to be to either make it privileged (which like I said, I am against since it will allow it to be called on an instance) or to *manually copy it* into each of my subclasses as a private method (which isn't much of a solution).

<s>Situation 2:</s>

```
(new sub()).A();
```

<s>When I resolve higher up the prototype chain, do I "reset"/start at the end at the next function call?</s>
**Yes.**

Comment: You say that "E" should never be invoked directly, but then that function "D" tries to invoke it directly ... it is therefore not clear what it is you want.  Are you trying to emulate a relationship that some inheritance systems call "protected" access from a subclass to a non-public base class method?

Comment: It's more than just protected access.  I don't want the method to be called on an instance, only from within other methods.  In javascript, the usual way to do this is to make it private via an anonymous function.  But as I have shown, that will not work in this scenario.

Comment: Ok - other than some of the perversions of Java "package" scope, that's generally what "protected" means to me :-)  Basic JavaScript scope however does not really have anything to do with inheritance, so in that sense the relationship between a "base" and instances of "sub" is no different than that between any other two function scopes.

Comment: Hmm...so am I correct in assuming that what I'm proposing is impossible to implement in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes.  A symbol declared in the scope of a function cannot be directly accessed from an outer scope.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454106/evaluate-subclass-method-inside-base-class-scope-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454106/evaluate-subclass-method-inside-base-class-scope-in-javascript)  Variant of the same question that gives a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following steps to create a class with private and public scope in JavaScript:

1. Create a normal prototype chain with only public members
2. Either mark public methods public or private members as private using a boolean set on the method itself. ( vis. `function foo() {}; foo._private = true;` )
3. Instantiate the chain inside an "interface class"
4. Iterate over the chain instance, creating references to its public members on the interface class
5. Rebind those references to the chain instance

Here's some code:

```
function BaseClass() {
  this.A = function A() {
    this.B();
  }
  this.B = function B() {}
  this.C = function C() {
    console.log('I am C');
  }
  this.C._private = true;
}

function Subclass() {
  this.D = function D() {
    this.C();
  }
  this.B = function B() {
    console.log('I am B');
  }
}
Subclass.prototype = new BaseClass();

function Interface() {

  var classScope = new Subclass();
  for ( var property in classScope ) {
    if ( !classScope[property]._private ) {
      this[property] = classScope[property].bind(classScope);
    }
  }
}

var classInstance = new Interface();
console.log(classInstance);
classInstance.A();
classInstance.B();
classInstance.D();
```

To see the output, checkout [this code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoLQbR?editors=001).

To see it with the code cleaned up a little bit to make the purpose of each expression a little clearer, [checkout this code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoLQOE?editors=001).

Note that `function C() {}` is fully encapsulated by `function Interface() {}` but `(new Interface()).D()` still has access to it.

Also, note that `(new Interface()).A()` calls `Subclass#B()`.