# Evaluate subclass method inside base class scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, class, inheritance

```
base = function () {
  this.A = function () {
    this.B();
  }
  var C = function () {
    alert('I am C');
  }
}

sub = function () {
  this.B = function () {
    C();
  }
}

sub.prototype = new base();

(new sub()).A();
```

How can I tell the call to `B()` to evaluate with respect to the base class?  (i.e. call c of the base class)  Is this impossible?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't wish to do `this.C = function(){...}` and call it as `this.C()`?

Comment: That would allow C to be called on instances / essentially expose it.  There's no reason for it to be exposed since it's supposed to be a helper method.  I guess you could say my main frustration is that helper methods can't be inherited by subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I would recommend `myFunc.apply` and `myFunc.eval`; that's what I interpret as "with respect to the base class" in javascript.

However based on your title, you say "inside base class scope"; if I assume correctly that you are talking about closures and being able to refer to variables in outer functions, this is impossible, except perhaps with keeping an entrypoint into the closure into which you can pass in requests eval-style... but if you do that, you might as well have a an object like `this._private.C`.

If you are attempting to keep things "private", it is not really worth bothering to do so in javascript.

If you say your motivation for `this.C = function(){...}` and access it as `this.C()`, I may be able to give a clearer answer.

> "*That would allow C to be called on instances / essentially expose it. There's no reason for it to be exposed since it's supposed to be a helper method. I guess you could say my main frustration is that helper methods can't be inherited by subclasses.*" --OP

In that case, it really isn't private. However what you can do is define your helper method where it belongs: appropriately in an outer scope. =) For example:

```
(function(){

  var C = function () {
    alert('I am C');
  }

  base = function () {
    this.A = function () {
      this.B();
    }
  }

  sub = function () {
    this.B = function () {
      C();
    }
  }

})();

sub.prototype = new base();

(new sub()).A();
```

Comment: Yes, call and apply is the key to invoke prototype object's method

Comment: @ninjagecko
You, sir, are a genius (or maybe I'm still a javascript newbie).  That outer scope was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @jiaweihli: no problem, I still wouldn't recommend stressing too much about hiding internals in javascript. Somewhat relatedly, though you don't seem to be a newbie at all, you should also be aware of the most common javascript pitfall: if you do any kind of iteration with `.map` or `$.each` or `for` loops, you will often need to write anonymous functions because only one variable with a single name is ever created per function. This is often noticed if defining callbacks in a loop.

Comment: @ninjagecko
Yes, JavaScript garden taught me that (and I learned it the hard way) :)

I do have a minor quibble with your solution after thinking about it for a while.  When C is placed outside both classes, it's no longer able to access the private variables within them (hence breaking its ability to be a 'helper' function).

Comment: @jiaweihli: that would be, I think, perhaps a use-case for `C.call(this, arg1,arg2,...)`? which would allow `C` to access `this.something`. --alternatively-- You might also be able to just declare `var C` where it is currently, and later define `C = function(){...}` inside the scope of `base`! This would probably not do what you want though.

Comment: @ninjagecko  
Ah, but that would force me to declare the variables as protected instead of private, which would once again make them accessible.  Javascript is tough love.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not without changing the base class.

`C` has *lexical* scope within `base`, so is only visible when called by other methods defined *within the same scope*.  It's currently a truly *private* method.

`C` can only be accessed outside of its lexical scope if it's declared as `this.C` instead of `var C`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/DaSEN/

Comment: It seems somehow ironic to me that I can access C() while evaluating A() since I am within the scope of the base class, but since it travels back down the prototype chain when calling this.B(), I can no longer access it.

Comment: @jiaweihli that's just how it works - think of `C` as the equivalent of a private method in Java or C++ and you'd have the same problem.